# How to define a button inside Manipulate that tells Mathematica to re-evaluate the whole Manipulate code?

Tags: front-end, manipulate

I have written a `Manipulate` code carrying out some very complicated tasks. There is no problem for the first run, but if I click the reset button to reset all variables to their initial states (which is also ok) and click the run button a second time, then it is very likely that the Mathematica kernel will crash during the re-run progress, the frequency for such crash happening is about 9 out of 10 times.

I have spent almost a month trying to track down the source of this problem, but failed. I also asked the Wolfram support team, they suggested to implement the `Quit` function in the reset button as a workaround, such that the reset button will make the kernel quit, since the first run is always ok.

Now the problem is, I cannot directly put `Quit[]` inside the button, for by doing this the kernel loses all definiton about the enclosing `Manipulate`. So I need the reset button doing two tasks:

1. Quit the kernel.
2. Make Mathematica automatically re-run the enclosing `Manipulate` code.

I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: Without a MWE (minimal working example) helping you will be difficult. Please provide code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Yves Klett The problem is I cannot come up with a minimal working example, because I have not tracked down the source of the crash. My code is about 900 lines, I fear it is too long to post here...

Comment: Can you use `Clear`  or `Remove`  with any success?

Comment: @ Yves klett I tried to use `Unset`, `ClearSystemCache`,`$HistoryLength`, `SaveDefinitions -> True`,
`SynchronousInitialization -> True`,
`SynchronousUpdating -> True`, and `DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> Infinity`. But the problem remains. There must be no problem for any function since the first run is always ok. I suppose something unusual happened in the kernel during the re-run process.

Comment: @Yves Klett I tried to use `Clear` and `Remove` instead of `Unset`, but problem also remains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is rather in not efficient/proper `Manipulate` structure but since it is 900 lines long I think we can't help to fix it.

Here's the solution you've asked, I think so, isn't it?

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{
          Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 12.4}],
          Button["reset",
                 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
                 SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
                 NotebookDelete@Cells[GeneratedCell -> True];
                 ClearAll["Global`*"];
                 SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]];
                ]
        }]
 , {n, .3, 11.8}]
```

Comment: Yes, in my code,the main operation is executed from inside the run button, not in the `Manipulate` body. About your code, I run it, the cell is deleted, but not generated again, even after I remove the ; after `SelectionEvaluate[]`.

Comment: @saturasl I've made one edit couple minutes ago, try if you have the exactly same version as it is now. What is Run button?

Comment: Ah, the run button, I was talknig about the button in my own code, not yours. Now your code works, exactly what I expect, Thanks!