# Manipulate that remembers its own input code and can show it by request

Tags: front-end, manipulate, replacement

This question is a further question to [my previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33381/5943). The solution for that question works well as long as the original input `Manipulate` code is still provided in the notebook. But in general, there are cases that only the output cell is included and the input code omitted. In such case, I think we could possily make the `Manipulate` remembers its own input code, and by request (e.g. a button) we can show the code.

A first attempt starts with either `DynamicModule` or `Pattern`. For instance, I tried

```
DynamicModule[{mc = HoldComplete@Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 12.4}],
   Button["show code",
    NotebookPut[Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[mc]], "Intput"]}], 
     EvaluationNotebook[]]
    ]}], {n, .3, 11.8}]},
 ReleaseHold[mc]]
```

where mc is the short for 'manipulatecode'. But the code will not be shown if we click the button, only the output instead.

I also tried

```
mem : Manipulate[
Column[{
Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 12.4}],
Button["show code",
 NotebookPut[Notebook[{Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[mc]], "Intput"]}], 
  EvaluationNotebook[]]
 ]}],
{n, .3, 11.8},
Initialization :> (mc := HoldComplete[mem];)]
```

But this will not work also. Is there a way to let the button creates a new cell and show the `Manipulate` code in this cell (better in expression format)?

Comment: Do you want to store the code to re-evaluate `Manipualte`or to show it? Printable CellData is not readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
manipulatecode = NotebookRead@EvaluationCell[];

Manipulate[
 Column[{
         Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 1}],
         Button["PrintCode", CellPrint[manipulatecode];]
       }]
 , {n, 0, 1}
 , SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

And then, even if you delete the input code you can print it. Does it fit your needs?

Comment: Thank you Kuba, I can try to add some additional functions based on  your solution now. Previously I was thinking on the direction of meta programming, but I was too busy to finish it.