# Refresh dynamic module

Tags: dynamic

What is the simplest way I can add a reset / refresh option to dynamic module / manipulate? This seems like a bit of a hack, but it gives approxiamately desired output:

```
Manipulate[
   Grid[Partition[DynamicModule[{x = a}, 
   Button[Text[Style[#, 24]], x = Mod[x + 1/2, 1], ImageSize -> {60, 60}, 
   Background -> Dynamic[Hue[1, 2 x, 1]]]] & /@ Range@100, 10], 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}], Invisible@Control[{a, {10^(-6), 0}}], 
   Button["Reset", If[a == 0, a = 10^(-6), a = 0]]]
```

What is the best way to achieve this without the workaround?

Comment: probably related: [**33452**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33452/5478),  [**72796**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72796/5478)

Comment: @Kuba updated now

Comment: Thanks for the update but it is till not clear what do you mean by reset here. There are 100 `DynamicModules` and one `Manipulate`, I suppose you refer to the outer `Manipulate` but we should not quess. Reseting particular DynamicMOdules is a reasonable question too.

Comment: @Kuba Well, I wrapped the `DynamicModule` in `Manipulate` - not sure whether that's necessary, but keeps it self-contained. I supopose I want to reset the `x` values, but I am not certain. I want to reset the cells to white at any rate. I had no idea there were so many `DynamicModules` BTW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you just want to reset the initial values, which means your life is actually relatively easy. The trick is to just wrap everything in a single `DynamicModule` and the system will take care of the rest. This takes a small amount of rewriting, but it's really quite quick and easy:

```
DynamicModule[{
  vals = AssociationMap[False &, Range[100]],
  entries = 100,
  partitioning = 10
  },
 Panel@Column@{
    Button["Reset",
     vals = AssociationMap[False &, Range[entries]]],
    Deploy@
     Grid[
      Partition[
       Table[
        With[{i = i},
         Item[
          EventHandler[
           Pane[i, {35, 35}, Alignment -> Center],
           "MouseClicked" :> (vals[i] = Not@vals[i])
           ],
          Background ->
           Dynamic@If[vals[i], Red, White]
          ]
         ],
        {i, Range[entries]}
        ],
       UpTo@partitioning
       ],
      Dividers -> All
      ]
    }
 ]
```

Since it's all one `DynamicModule` the front-end will track the variables for you, and all you have to do is reset the initial state in a `Button` by a simple assignment.

Comment: this is great! Many thanks :) Much better that my attempt - will have to look into your construction when  I get a moment. Will give it another 24 hrs before I mark the accept.