# Manipulate: How to create custom reset Button automatically?

Tags: manipulate, core-language, gui-construction

I have a complex `Manipulate` with more than 10 controls.
Each one has its own default value.

I'd like to add a custom button in the control area to reset all control's values to their default values.

That's exactly what the "*Initial Settings*" in the `Manipulate` menu (+ on the up left corner) does.
But I'd like to bring this action to a custom button located near my custom play/pause buttons.

I've searched the forum and I've read that "Initial settings" is a sort of bookmark, created automatically (?).

Yet I can't find how to execute this option from a custom button (or call that sort of automatic bookmark from a different control).

I've found many posts about setting the bookmarks programmatically, but no answer on the simpler question about how to invoke the "Initial settings" option from outside the manipulate menu.

I know that I could assign all the default values one by one (within the custom button) but that seems silly to me since there's already a similar option in the + menu.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are those answers useful? [31344](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31344/5478) if so, I'd say it is a duplicate.

Comment: No, I had read them. They just suggest to use the default AppearanceElements -> "ResetButton" (not a custom button) or use a custom button to set all controls to their default values, thing that I'd like to avoid (if possible) having a long list (possibly growing) of controls.

Comment: I am not following your question. You mean you want to make a button on the fly somehow? Why not just code a button that when clicked resets the other control to their initial values? Like this: `Manipulate[
 Row[{a, b, c}],
 {{a, 6, "a"}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{b, 7, "b"}, 0, 10, 1},
 {{c, 8, "c"}, 0, 10, 1},
 Button["Reset", a = 6; b = 7; c = 8]
 ]` I must be not understanding the question.

Comment: @Nasser Because this is not fun at all! :)

Comment: @Nasser I was just wandering if the same operation accomplished by your code could be made more easily and in a smarter way through some calling to the built-in "Initial Settings" option. Imagine having 20 controls and tweaking tentatively their default values to find the best working  Initial Settings for a demonstration. Following your suggestion I'd have to change their default values twice (in each control and in the reset button). Or, alternatively, I'd have to add 20 new variables to the code to set the default values and to be then used both in the controls and in the Reset button.

Answer (score 6):

Less ambitious:

```
addbutton[manipulate_] := 
 With[{box = ToBoxes@manipulate}, 
  With[{proc = Cases[box, HoldPattern["Variables" :> _], ∞]}, 
   With[{button = Button["Reset", CompoundExpression["Variables"] /. proc]}, 

    Composition[ToExpression, BoxData][
     box /. {("Body" :> x_) :> "Body" :> Column[{button, x}]}]]]]

addbutton@Manipulate[Dynamic[x], {x, 0, 1}]

CDFDeploy[ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory}, "Manipulate.cdf"], %]
```

---

More ambitious but:

As Jinxed has noticed, it fails when deployed to CDF with `Export` or `CDFDeploy`. However it works by File \ CDF export menu.

The reason is that it produces structure which is not quite correct, enough to work instantly in FE though.

```
addbutton[manipulate_] := With[{box = ToBoxes @ manipulate},
  With[{
    proc = Cases[box, HoldPattern["Variables" :> _], ∞]        
    },       
   With[{
     button = Button["Reset", CompoundExpression["Variables"] /. proc]
     },        
    Composition[ CellPrint, Cell[#, "Output"] &, BoxData
      ][
     box /. {
      ("Specifications" :> {x__}) :> "Specifications" :> {x, button},
      HoldPattern[Typeset`specs$$ = {y__}] :> (Typeset`specs$$ = {y, {Hold[button], 
        Manipulate`Dump`ThisIsNotAControl}})
      }
     ]
    ]
   ]]
```

---

```
addbutton[
 Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], 
             {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 4}, 
             {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Works really well, except in CDFs. Maybe when wrapped in a `DynamicModule`'s `Initialization`.

Comment: I managed to wrap it, but then the CDF shows three copies of the `Manipulate`.

Comment: `DynamicModule[{}, Null;, SaveDefinitions -> True, 
 Initialization :> 
  addbutton[
   Manipulate[
    Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 
     4}, {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10}]]]`

Comment: Otherwise (with your approach applied "pure" and exported) I get nothing more than `Hold[Null] {} {}` (on three lines). I did the export to CDF using `Export["<filename>", %<Out>]`.

Comment: @Jinxed Confirmend, But when you use `File\\Export as cdf` it works

Comment: Interesting. Why might that be?

Comment: @Jinxed I've found the deifference but it still produces not deployable code. Unless via Menu File Export CDF.

Answer (score 4):

Not completely tested, based on undocumented structure of the `DynamicModule` constructed by `Manipulate` -- but it works for now:

```
Manipulate[a + b + c,
 {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 2}, 0, 5}, {c, 0, 5},
 Button["Reset",
  Replace[
   Typeset`specs,
   {{{Hold[var_Symbol], val_}, ___} :> (var = val),
     {Hold[var_Symbol], val_, ___} :> (var = val)},
   1]]
 ]
```

**Update.** A combination of Kuba's and my ideas:  We construct the code for the button from the code for the `Manipulate`.  More likely not to break in future versions.

```
SetAttributes[addreset, HoldAll];
addreset[Manipulate[body_, specs___]] :=
 With[{btn = Button["Reset", CompoundExpression @@ #] &@Replace[
      Hold[specs],
      {{{var_Symbol, val_}, ___} :> (var = val),
       {var_Symbol, val_, ___} :> (var = val),
       _ -> Sequence[]},
      1]},
  Manipulate[body, specs, btn]
  ]

addreset@Manipulate[a + b + c,
  {{a, 1}, 0, 5}, {{b, 2}, 0, 5}, {c, 0, 5}
  ]
```

Comment: Nice, I met Typeset family today, I should've tried this but I'm always overwhelmed by what is in those undocumented boxes :) p.s. built-in reset button resets to the very initial values, even if you save cdf and new values are preserved, it always goes back to the beginning. Do you find this intuitive?, one could argue, I was surprised for example

Comment: @Kuba Thanks. From the programming point of view, they are the initial values being reset.  It's less clear perhaps for the user in some applications.  But `Manipulate` is not exactly a robust user-application environment.  It really seems meant for small, single-purpose demo apps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not insisting on calling the `Manipulate`-menu's bookmark, the following approach might do the job:

```
Manipulate[Column[{Plot[TriangleWave[a x], {x, 0, 1}],
 Button["Custom Reset",
        (* first go back within the notebook *)
        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
        SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
        (* then reevaluate the Manipulate[]-expression *)
        SelectionEvaluate[EvaluationNotebook[]];]
 }],{{a, 2}, 1, 10}]
```

However: This approach does not work with Computable Documents.

Comment: Thanks. Clever. Thanks also for the advice about CD. Unfortunately that's just my case as I need to make a CDF from my notebook when it's finished (to be used by my students). So I'm afraid I must go for the manual settings of all the control values in the custom button...

Comment: [related ;)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33381/5478)

Comment: Sorry. I use `SelectionMove`approach for jumping around within presentation notebooks quite a lot. :(

I wasn't my intention to "steal" from you.

Comment: @Jinxed It wasn't my intention to mak you feel guilty! :)