# Is it possible to return a list of variable values set by Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

Is it possible to write a function that returns a set of values that are set by `Manipulate`?

For example, a function that returns a dataset of variables modified by `Manipulate` when an "Update" button is clicked. For example, would it be possible to return `treatmentSpecRow` from the `EKSWaveformControl` function below or make it accessible outside of the local scope of 
`EKSWaveFormControl`?

```
EKSWaveFormControl[] :=
  DynamicModule[{treatmentSpecRow},
    Manipulate[
      Plot[ctrlVdc + ctrlVac ctrlgFunc[2 π ctrlf t + ctrlPhi], {t, 0, 0.4}],
      {{ctrlgFunc, Sin, ""}, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}},
      Delimiter,
      {{ctrlVac, 1.5, Subscript["V", "ac"]}, -10, 10}, 
      {{ctrlVdc, 0.5, Subscript["V", "dc"]}, -1, 1},
      Delimiter,
      {{ctrlf, 10, "Frequency"}, 0.001, 100},
      {{ctrlPhi, 0, "ϕ"}, 0, 2 π}, 
      Delimiter,
      Button["Update",
        treatmentSpecRow = 
          Dataset[Association @ 
            {Func -> ctrlgFunc, Vac -> ctrlVac, Vdc -> ctrlVdc, 
             ϕ -> ctrlPhi, ω -> 2 π ctrlf}]], 
       ControlPlacement -> Left,
       Paneled -> True,
       LocalizeVariables -> True]]
```

Comment: Here's a similar question: [15090](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15090/how-to-extract-the-numerical-value-of-a-dynamical-variable).

Comment: Hi m_goldberg - I have posted an example.  In the example, I would like to obtain a Dataset of values changed during a Manipulate session. In the example I would like to return the treatmentSpecRow Dataset from EKSWaveFormControl[] when the Update button is clicked. This will be one of several controls in a complex computation that can be somewhat time consuming.  I would like to let users set parameters in multiple controls, take all of the control settings and start the run with parameters from multiple controls.

Comment: `Manipulate` has a feature that delivers almost what you want. It is **Paste Snapshot**, which appears on the **Bookmarks/Autorun** pop-up menu. Click on the (+) button at the upper right conner of the `Manipulate` panel. This writes the values you want, and some other stuff, to new input cell.

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg, I wonder if there is a way to call the **Paste Snapshot** could be called programmatically.   The reason being that many of the end-users will be running this via a CDF and will not be seasoned Mathematica users.  If I could make save  variables updated in Manipulate to a list available outside of the manipulate, that would be ideal.

Comment: @DougKimzey so are you alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you ask, but here is an alternative approach that you might use.

```
snapshots = {};
Manipulate[
  Plot[ctrlVdc + ctrlVac ctrlgFunc[2 π ctrlf t + ctrlPhi], {t, 0, 0.4}],
  {{ctrlgFunc, Sin, ""}, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}},
  Delimiter,
  {{ctrlVac, 1.5, Subscript["V", "ac"]}, -10, 10}, 
  {{ctrlVdc, 0.5, Subscript["V", "dc"]}, -1, 1},
  Delimiter,
  {{ctrlf, 10, "Frequency"}, 0.001, 100},
  {{ctrlPhi, 0, "ϕ"}, 0, 2 π}, 
  Delimiter,
  Button["Update",
    snapshots = 
      {snapshots, <|Func -> ctrlgFunc, Vac -> ctrlVac, Vdc -> ctrlVdc, 
                    ϕ -> ctrlPhi, ω -> 2 π ctrlf|>}],
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: demo]

Evaluate the following after the `Manipulate` panel appears if you want to see how `snapshots` changes each time **Update** is clicked.

```
Dynamic @ Column @ Flatten @ snapshots
```

> ```
> <|Func -> Sin, Vac -> 1.5, Vdc -> 0.5, ϕ -> 0, ω -> 20 π|>}, 
> <|Func -> Tan, Vac -> -6.3, Vdc -> 0.5, ϕ -> 0, ω -> 140.743|>
> ```

When you have all the snapshots you want, evaluate

```
ds = Dataset[Flatten @ snapshots]
```

[image: dataset]

The dataset is not displayed in a nice table form because you chose to have symbols for keys; you need to use string keys to get the nice looking table.

Answer (score 0):

To make more automatic approach we can use some knowledge shared by [MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2): [Manipulate: How to create custom reset Button automatically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72821/5478)

```
EKSWaveFormControl[] :=  Manipulate[
   Plot[ctrlVdc + ctrlVac ctrlgFunc[2 \[Pi] ctrlf t + ctrlPhi], {t, 0,
      0.4}], 
  {{ctrlgFunc, Sin, ""}, {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot}}, 
   Delimiter, 
  {{ctrlVac, 1.5, Subscript["V", "ac"]}, -10,   10}, 
  {{ctrlVdc, 0.5, Subscript["V", "dc"]}, -1, 1}, 
   Delimiter, 
  {{ctrlf, 10, "Frequency"}, 0.001,  100}, 
  {{ctrlPhi, 0, "\[Phi]"}, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   Delimiter,

  Button["Update", 
    externalVar =  Association[
      Cases[Typeset`specs,  
        Hold[s_Symbol] :> (StringTrim[SymbolName[Unevaluated@s],
                                      "$$" ~~ NumberString
                                     ] -> s), 
        \[Infinity]]]]



   ,
   ControlPlacement -> Left, Paneled -> True, 
   LocalizeVariables -> True]


EKSWaveFormControl[]
Dynamic @ externalVar
```

> ```
> (*manipulate panel*)
> <|ctrlgFunc->Sin,ctrlVac->6.45,ctrlVdc->0.5,ctrlf->10,ctrlPhi->0|>
> ```