# Get value of symbol

Tags: manipulate, symbols

```
ab := {{a, 10, 100}, {b, 0, 10}}
Manipulate[a*b, Evaluate[Delete[ab, 0]], Button["SHow", Print[Evaluate[Symbol[ToString[ab[[1]][[1]]]]]]; Print[a, "---", b]]]
```

In the above example, I am having controls info in a variable ab. Now how to get the value of control variables without directly referring to a and b.

When I clicked the SHow button, I am getting the value if I explicitly print a & b. However I want to get these values using ab.

I tried Evaluate[Symbol[ToString[ab[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me1L0.png)][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me1L0.png)]]]], but it is not working.

Is there any other simple way?
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What do you want? Where do you want to get the value of the control variables?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I want the value of "a" when "SHow" button is clicked . But without explicitly printing "a"

Comment: Ah, I see. I think this is nearly a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10604/how-are-parameters-evaluated-for-a-plot-in-manipulate where the answer is "make `a, b` parameters of a function instead".

Comment: @PatrickStevens thanks for the link. But there is a difference that in my case, I don't know about my control variables explicitly. I have to access it only through "ab". Correct me if I am missing anything

Comment: The problem is that `a` and `b` are scoped and the full name of each is something like ``FE`a$$43``.

Comment: p.s.do you agree it's a duplicate? [81380](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81380/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the global symbols hidden in the definition of `ab` are not localized in the `Manipulate`.  `Manipulate` reassigns the `a` and `b` that appear in the code passed to `Manipulate` by `Evaluate[Delete[ab, 0]]` to localized `DynamicModule` symbols, which are then remapped to front-end dynamic variables whenever the `Manipulate` output is instantiated in the front end.  (It's a complicated process, which you can read about in the four tutorials on `Manipulate` and dynamic functionality, as well as on this site.)

So one easy way to get the sample code to work the way that is asked is to evaluate `ab` before it is passed to `Manipulate`.  The OP's ultimate goal seems unclear, not only to me but to some commenters.  It is possible that in a more complicated use-case, the following might not work due to reasons specific to the use-case.  However, it works on the present example.

```
ab := {{a, 10, 100}, {b, 0, 10}}
Manipulate[a*b, Evaluate[Delete[ab, 0]], 
 Evaluate@With[{ab = ab}, 
   Button["SHow", Print[ab[[1, 1]]]; 
    Print[a, "---", b]]
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update notice: Originally, I had simply modify the `Button` to remove the `Symbol` thus: `Print[Evaluate[ToString[ab[[1]][[1]]]]`. While that was accepted, on second thoughts, I thought printing the actual value instead a string representation seemed more in line with the wording of the question.

Comment: It would be nice to have `ParentDynamicModuleNumber[]`  function finally.

Comment: @Kuba Wouldn't it though?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider this simple form, which cuts the Gordian knot by making each control show its current value.

```
ctrls := {{a, 10, 100}, {b, 0, 10}};
Manipulate[a*b,
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ (Append[#, Appearance -> "Labeled"] & /@ ctrls)]]
```

[image: demo]

This will work no matter how many controls are specified in the list `curls` as long as each element of the list has the proper form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is how to get the value after pressing the button. Basically I want to pass the controls' value (value of "a" & "b" in your example) to a function and I am not able to access its value by using controls list (which is "ctrls" in your example)